# How to transfer data between 3 components in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to `Vue.js` and I want to do a simple todo app. I have a **template** for a new item, then, when data is filled, I click the **add button** which pushes new item to the final **list**. The problem is my **add button** located in another section so I don't have a parent-child connection. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7hpH.png) is my mockup (red lines are sections separators).
I've read lots of articles and same questions on stack overflow, but I didn't find them really helpful in my case.

Here is my code for **template**:

```
<template>
    <div ref="template" class="task-template">
        <div class="task-template__wrapper">
            <div class="task-template__input">
                <input v-model="todo.header" :value="todo.header" ref="header" class="task-template__header" type="text" placeholder="Название задачи" @input="triggerEvent">
            </div>
            <div class="task-template__input">
                <input v-model="todo.description" :value="todo.description" ref="description" class="task-template__description" type="text" placeholder="Описание" @input="triggerEvent">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="task-template__actions">
            <div class="task-template__actions_inner">
                <inline-svg class="task-template__btn hover" alt="Подзадачи"
                            :src="getImageUrl(`bulleted-list.svg`)"></inline-svg>
                <inline-svg class="task-template__btn" alt="Добавить в группу"
                            :src="getImageUrl(`folder.svg`)"></inline-svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "TodoTemplate",
    props: {
        todo: {
            header: "",
            description: "",
            tasks: [],
            groups: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        triggerEvent(todo) {
            this.$emit('input', todo);
        }
    }
}
```

For **add button**:

```
<template>
    <div class="add-button" @click="submit">
        <div class="add-button__container">
            Добавить задачу
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "CreateTodo",
    data() {
        return {
            todo: {
                header: "",
                description: "",
                tasks: [],
                groups: []
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit: () => {
            this.$emit("saveData", )
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

For **list**:

```
<template>
    <section>
        <TodoTemplate></TodoTemplate>
        <ul class="todo">
            <TodoItem v-for="todo in todos" :title="todo.header" :key="todo"></TodoItem>
        </ul>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import TodoTemplate from "@/components/TodoTemplate/TodoTemplate";
import TodoItem from "@/components/TodoItem/TodoItem";

export default {
    name: "TodoList",
    components: {TodoItem, TodoTemplate},
    data() {
        return {
            todos: [
                {
                    header: '  Купить шампанское',
                    description: '"Dom Perignon", Rose Vintage 2003 Brut',
                    tasks: [],
                    groups: []
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addTodo(todo) {
            this.todos.push({
                header: todo.header,
                description: todo.description,
                tasks: todo.tasks,
                groups: todo.groups
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Is there any ways to do it without extra libs like `Vuex`? Or I should merge those two sections? Thanks!

Comment: Your CreateTodo component ('add' button) needs to be imported into a parent component in order to communicate with the parent.  However, I recommend not creating the separate CreateTodo component. Just add a regular button to your TodoTemplate component.  The button can call an event handler defined in TodoTemplate to trigger adding the todo.  Search the web for Vue Todo tutorials.

Comment: yes, you were absolutely right! I read some documentation, reduced number of components and now it works fine :)